# How to set the python runtime on AWS when using c7n-org to create custodian rule

Tags: cloudcustodian

How to set the python runtime version on AWS when using c7n-org to create custodian rule,we are getting 3.9 version on lambda but we are deploying rule with our local machine which uses python version 3.11

We created virtual environment with new python version but didn't helped.